# Updating Entity Framework model throws DirectoryNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

We can do the initial import from DB into new EDMX but any subsequent effort to update/add/other throws this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occured
>   while attempting to update from the database.  The exception message
>   is: 'Could not find part of the path
>   'c:\temp\user1.edmx\tmp622D.edmx'.'

I cannot recreate this in any other environment but each machine in the building suffers this same issue?  Destroying the .edmx all together and doing a fresh import works, but everything else throws and exception regarding this temp file...

So far, I have proven I can create / edit files in the temp folder, and I have tried running VS as admin....

Answer (score 0):

'c:\temp\user1.edmx\tmp622D.edmx'.'

Why does your path have an extra **'.**?

Comment: I am not convinced it is a 'permissions' issue.  New project, new model, from db, add 2 tables, save all....  Things are good.  Right click edmx designer -> update model from database, click finish, error.

Comment: what is your connection string in the web config? (remember to remove the password)

Comment: BAM!  Still not 100% sure what is going on behind the scenes that this breaks but I have confirmed that GPO is altering the "user environmental variables'  when I manually set them back to '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp' EF4 works fine, when I let the GPO apply a custom temp directory it all falls apart...  The drama continues, but it is no longer a painful mystery!  Any thoughts on why a custom path like 'c:\temp\user1.tmp' would break EF or what we can do about it?

Comment: I was copying the 'error message', not sure, in real life the TEMP folder and TMP folder in environment variables seems valid, no extra '.' or other.  It reads specfically as c:\temp\userA.tmp when I drill through windows to consider/edit it.